# text based proxy on port 80

Tags: text, proxy, port

My internet access is restricted to ports 80 and 443. These ports will only be given data if it comes with appropriate Content-Type so you cannot download any flv files for instance. Is there a solution out there or a mixture of solutions to route the whole traffic via a php script? So for instance there could be something running in the system which would capture the whole traffic, covert outgoing traffic to requests to a php script, then the script would act as my computer, obtain response and covert the response to text. Since text is allowed then the program running on my machine would convert text back to incoming traffic. A bit like proxy. Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible, but since there's no standard for that kind of proxy, you'll have to make your own custom proxy server and place it in a remote web server outside of your ISP. You also have to write your own proxy on your side to tunnel standard HTTP/HTPS from your web browser to the remote custom proxy.

Comment: Is there a non painful way of controlling all the in/out traffic before it goes to / after receiving it from modem, on windows?

Comment: For that question, there's a _proxifier_ software that redirect all conections to a HTTP/HTTPS/SOCKS proxy. I only know one named `Proxifier`, but it's 32-bit and I don't know if it's compatible with Vista/Windows7. You can use that to redirect all connections to your own custom proxy in local PC without having to configure each of your network related programs.